# Should I pass the Localizer to ViewData in .net core Globalization?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

```cs
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization

@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = Localizer["HomeTitle"];
}

<h1 class="page-header">@ViewData["HomeTitle"]</h1>
```

Here is an extract of Globalization and localization tutorial by microsoft.

I feel strange that I must pass Localizer to ViewData, instead of just using

```
<h1 class="page-head">@Localizer["HomeTitle"]</h1>
```

Is that has something special use? Or just only a trouble made by Microsoft?

Comment: You can simply use the syntax `@Localizer["StringToTranslate"]`. There's no requirement to pass it to the `ViewData`.

Comment: Also in the future, please write the source code instead of using a screenshot.

Comment: @Métoule Yeah,my option is just like you.However I am a beginer of .net core so I am not sure if I can do it like this.

Comment: @Métoule OK,Thank you.

Comment: You can look at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1#view-localization for more info on globalization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the example is over complicated: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-2.1#view-localization

Probably their idea was: `ViewData["Title"]` is used by the layout to set the `<title/>` in the html head.

So than putting `ViewData["Title"] = Localizer["HomeTitle"];` in the view the master layout can use `ViewData["Title"]`.

So you can have layout.cshtml:

```
<head><title>@ViewData["Title"]</title></head>
```

homepage.cshtml:

```
ViewData["Title"] = Localizer["HomeTitle"];
```

contact.cshtml:

```
ViewData["Title"] = Localizer["ContactTitle"];
```

So this way you could set a different title, but still define the page-layout/html in the layout.cshtml file (and thus abstractly re-using code).

### conclusion

```
 ViewData["Title"] = Localizer["HomeTitle"];
```

is not needed. But it's a way to give informations/specific translations to a layout page.